# Google sign integration not working

Tags: web, google-signin

I followed this guide to integrate google sign in: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

But when I click the sign in button a pop up comes and goes but doesn't provide any information of the user.

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {

    // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
    console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
    console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
    console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

    // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
  };
```

In console I am not getting any information.

Comment: How does the entire code look?

Comment: @Vlad I already fixed the problem. I made mistake in generating Client ID in google console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using right URL with the port number in Authorized JavaScript origins field in "Create a Project and Client ID" section.
And I also enabled Google+ Api for the project.